# Google Analytics V3 vs V4

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I want to implement Google Analytics in my android app. I'm not interested in eCommerce and Global Tracking. All I want to track is the screens visited and events generated by users.
Tried using Google Analytics V3 and it works fine. 
Want to migrate to V4 (Should I?).
Google Analytics V4 is now integrated with Google Play Services, which is HUGE. I now get [this](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html) 65K method problem in android.

Found a good article on that [here](https://medium.com/@rotxed/dex-skys-the-limit-no-65k-methods-is-28e6cb40cf71). The Google Play Services Modular structure is for Gradle. I'm using Eclipse with the android SDK.

Is there any similar work around? Why add the huge library when you just want to use a part of it?

Comment: Are you using Gradle? Google offers [granular dependencies for Google Play Services](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#split) so you only need to include what you need and not the whole thing.

Comment: Nope. I'm using Eclipse with SDK.

Comment: Stop using Eclipse, migrate to Android Studio, it will handle large libraries automatically

Comment: Yup. Will migrate to Studio eventually. Have time constraints now. Should I  continue using V3 (oh it's deprecated) or try the fixes given  here: https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

I can't migrate to studio right now.